# can't get facebook friends from API

Tags: python, facebook

It came to my attention that facebook has a sweet API for us to use and I wanted to create an App to get friends birthdays, but even though I have the Token with all the permissions, it doesn't work.

I've tried to add every permission to my token, tried to write me/friends on the facebook api page and it doesn't show the data, just the following:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1013
  }
}
```

```py
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
friends = graph.get_object("me/friends")
```

Comment: That is correct. You can only get information about people that granted permission to your app. So have all your friends grant permission to your app and then it will work.

Comment: @WizKid how do they grant permission to my app?

Comment: You show them the Facebook Login button for your app which when they click on it will ask them for permission